# open source code development

Tags: source-code

I want to develop the application engine in the blender but I will improve the open source how to improve it as you will recommend the book , site , lesson , video anything. Please can you help

Comment: Hello :). If you want to help with Blender Development, you can check their [Development page](https://www.blender.org/get-involved/developers/).